# Why no AO darkening mode in cycles?

Tags: materials

Just been playing with the Gooseberry build of blender and there is a AO darkening mode for the view port. This would be so so useful in cycles itself as the current AO setting only lightens things.

I know you can darken using anAO pass in post pro but that is not practical when you need to preview things fast.

Comment: Because it's not yet fully implemented and stable, I would assume. It hasn't been announced too long ago, at: http://code.blender.org/index.php/2014/12/future-viewport-the-design/

Comment: If you feel like compiling it yourself, you can get the code here: https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/viewport_experiments/